# My app doesn't react at the didSelectRowAtIndex: method

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

i don't know what I am doing wrong, but my app is not working as expected. I have a tableview controller, and today I have included the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method to open a detail view from the selected row, but when tapping on the row nothing happens. Here is my code, maybe you find the reason why it is not firing the detail view.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "AddToDoViewController.h"
#import "EditToDoViewController.h"


@interface RootViewController ()
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize fetchedResultsController, managedObjectContext,AddToDoButton;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self setTitle:@"Today"];
  [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]];





  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
  {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
  }
}
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSManagedObject *managedObject = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  [[cell textLabel] setText:[[managedObject valueForKey:@"thingName"] description]];
  [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[[managedObject valueForKey:@"thingDescription"] description]];
  [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:17.0f];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:15.0f];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    EditToDoViewController *detailViewController = [[EditToDoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditToDoViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    detailViewController.selectedObject = selectedObject;

}




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
  return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
  }

  [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

  return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
  {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
      NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      abort();
    }
  }   
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath 
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
{  
  NSMutableArray *things = [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

  // Grab the item we're moving.
  NSManagedObject *thing = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];

  // Remove the object we're moving from the array.
  [things removeObject:thing];
  // Now re-insert it at the destination.
  [things insertObject:thing atIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];

  // All of the objects are now in their correct order. Update each
  // object's displayOrder field by iterating through the array.
  int i = 0;
  for (NSManagedObject *mo in things)
  {
    [mo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i++] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
  }

  [things release], things = nil;

  [managedObjectContext save:nil];
}






#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller
- (IBAction)AddToDoAction:(id)sender {

    AddToDoViewController *viewController = [[AddToDoViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
  if (fetchedResultsController) return fetchedResultsController;

  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = 
               [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FavoriteThing" 
                           inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = 
              [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayOrder" 
                                          ascending:YES];

  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] 
                              initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];  
  [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

  NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = 
              [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                  managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                    sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"ThingsCache"];
  aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
  [self setFetchedResultsController:aFetchedResultsController];

  [aFetchedResultsController release];
  [fetchRequest release];
  [sortDescriptor release];
  [sortDescriptors release];

  return fetchedResultsController;
}    

- (void)dealloc {
  [fetchedResultsController release];
  [managedObjectContext release];


  [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Here is my header file code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *AddToDoButton;
- (IBAction)AddToDoAction:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 EditToDoViewController *detailViewController = [[EditToDoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditToDoViewController" bundle:nil];
 NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 detailViewController.selectedObject = selectedObject;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

you forgot to push your view controller.

Comment: @mvasco this looks like what is missing.  Ignore my suggestions until you try adding this.  Also add a NSLog() to see if the didSelect method ever gets called.

Comment: Thank you both, @johnMa and Duncan Groenewald, the proposed solution of johnMa makes the app crashing...warning issue: 'Instance method: _pushViewController.animate not found...

Comment: Are you sure you have your `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`?